# imake on fedora 25 doesn't work

Tags: fedora, make, cmake

I tried to personalize the Makefile.tmpl makefile.rules and since then I can’t get the imake to run anymore under Fedora 25.

The command `xmkmf -a` gets me the following

```
mv -f Makefile Makefile.bak

imake -DUseInstalled -I/usr/share/X11/config
In file included from Imakefile.c:34:0:
/usr/share/X11/config/Imake.tmpl:2144:0: error: #include expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>
#include ProjectRulesFile
In file included from Imakefile.c:34:0:
/usr/share/X11/config/Imake.tmpl:2157:0: error: #include expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>
#include ProjectTmplFile

In file included from Imakefile.c:34:0:
/usr/share/X11/config/Imake.tmpl:2224:0: error: macro "MakefileTarget" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given
MakefileTarget()

imake:Exit code 1.
Stop.
```

I need to reinstall imake so that it starts working.

Answer (score 0):

Fedora 25 : `# dnf reinstall imake`

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to re-install from my own sources ? like an old copy of imake ?

Comment: and how do I rebuild it once i modify the imake.tmpl  file ? If I just run your command it won;'t rebuild imake. Apparently the source file says that whenever I modify it I should rebuild it